# Address of assets in substrate blockchain

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Every ERC20 token ethereum contract has an address. Substrate has [assets](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0/pallet_assets/index.html) pallet.

How will I get the address of the assets or tokens so that it can be listed on [exchanges](https://polkaswap.io/#/wallet)?

Comment: The assets pallet does not use addresses, it uses indices to identify the assets instead.

Comment: Then, how will I link the assets in AMM exchanges without the address?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. If you want a canonical location on one particular chain: That will be the asset id. It will not change for the lifetime of a chain.
If you want a canonical location for all chains using the assets pallet: I don't think that will be possible.

Comment: Hi Amiya, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: I already supported it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll need a wrapper for your native tokens. This could be done, for example, via bridge between your network and another network that have smart contracts supporting ERC-20 standard enabled.